# CardCornerRadius is not clipping linear layout within view

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-cardview, rounded-corners

I am trying to have images in my recycler view have rounded corners to look better. I looked online and found out I could not set the background to a cardview but I could set a background to a linear layout so that is what I did. In the design tab of Android Studio I can see that the cardview has rounded corners but when I run the app the corners are not rounded. I tried googling the problem for a few hours but I could not find an answer.

Here is the contrast on what I am seeing in Android studio and the emulator
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvPhoto"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#CABCBC"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPhoto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/_0443265_10154716579055043_2084238995361491869_o"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="name"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvSurname"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cvPhoto"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSurname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="surname"
    android:textColor="@color/gold"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cvPhoto" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:text="Rank"
    android:textColor="@color/gold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.503" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/next_arrow" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: maybe your linearlayout background is overlapping the corner radius of your cardview. try removing linearlayout once and you'll know if you actually have a corner radius to card view or not.

Comment: I set the linear layout to invisible and when I ran my app I saw the cardview had the rounded corners I wanted for the linear layout.

Comment: I guess you can simply use an ImageView instead of Linear Layout and it should fulfill your requirement. Even though if that doesn't work then you'll need to give corner radius to your linear layout as well

Answer (score 0):

I read some comments that suggest to move your linearlayout to have effects that you would like but I suggest to let your linearlayout and instead do like this:

1. put some padding between your cardview and your linearlayout:

   ```
   app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
   android:padding="16dp"
   ```

   don't miss cardUseCompatPadding flag!
2. put your corners radius and elevation like this:

   ```
   app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_elevation"
   app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_corners_radius"
   ```
3. set cardBackground to white color and transparent color for the constraintLayout parent;

   ```
   app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white" for cardview
   android:background="@color/transparent" for parent layout
   ```

and you're all done.