# CardView cardCornerRadius is not displayed on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-design-library, android-developer-api

I have a little problem with displaying cardCornerRadius in my CardView. Everything works fine on the emulator, but as soon as I test the app on my real device, I no longer see a corner radius around my CardView. What could be the reason ? API Level Emulator 28 (PIE)

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        >
    
     ... 
  </LinearLayout>
```

Mobile View:
[image]

Emulator View:

Comment: screenshot of image in mobile

Comment: Put your card view out of linear layout

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66299621/cardcornerradius-is-not-clipping-linear-layout-within-view). Your problem's solution is here.

Comment: But i need the LinearLayout...

Comment: Can you explain your XML code, you have wrap_content has a height that why it's not adding and showing the corner radius

Comment: Make you linear layout background transparent

Answer (score 0):

try this if you are using `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest:

delete this line, because this line prevents card view from showing radius.